# "Bitmap size exceeds VM budget" although function is optimized in Android

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I know, you can find hundreds of questions about this special topic, but I've read most of them and they didn't help. Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:573)
at PACKAGE.MyApp.getPhoto(MyApp.java:191)
at PACKAGE.MyApp.getEntries(MyApp.java:149)
at PACKAGE.AlarmSetup.createNotifications(AlarmSetup.java:48)
at PACKAGE.AlarmSetup.onHandleIntent(AlarmSetup.java:30)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

This exception is thrown although I have optimized my Java function (at least I think so) after having read lots of questions here on Stack Overflow. Here's my code:

```
public Bitmap getContactPhoto(String lookup_key) {
    Uri lookUpUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookup_key);
    Uri contentUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(ctx.getContentResolver(), lookUpUri);
    try {
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 144;
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // first get only the size of the image
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), contentUri), null, o);
        int scale = 1;
        while ((o.outWidth/scale/2) >= REQUIRED_SIZE && (o.outHeight/scale/2) >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options oScaled = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        oScaled.inSampleSize = scale; // decode with calculated sample size now
        oScaled.inPurgeable = true; // prevent OutOfMemory
        oScaled.inInputShareable = true; // prevent OutOfMemory
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), contentUri), null, oScaled);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can you help me? I'm becoming desperate, tried a lot of improvements. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This bit of code looks good to me. So what are you doing with the bitmaps later? How many of these do you keep in memory?

Comment: The bitmaps are all saved in an `ArrayList<Person>` and every single object of `Person` is then displayed in a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might not lay in this code segment. Maybe you created a lot of bitmap instances that can not be able to garbage collected. Try to use MAT ([Memory Analysis for Android Applications](http://android-developers.blogspot.tw/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)) to check if there such instances.

Comment: The bitmaps are all saved in an `ArrayList<Person>` and displayed in a `ListView`. So there might be a reference to every single bitmap in the `ArrayList` which prevents them from being garbage collected. But this is right, isn't it, because I still need them for displaying at this point.

Comment: You could consider to keep these bitmaps into [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html). Keeping bitmaps that is visible to user would help.

Comment: Well, you might be legitimately be running out of memory then. You need to decode the images on the fly as opposed to keeping them in the array.

Comment: Thank you! @Julian Shen: `LruCache` is not available for the API levels I'm developing for, unfortunately. @dmon: Do you mean that I should only decode the bitmaps if the user scrolls to their position in the listview? Isn't that much slower? Scrolling might not be fluent anymore, right?

Comment: Yes only decode as you show them. It will be fast enough for thumbnail size bitmaps.